# How to make rows into columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table

```
SELECT PolicyID, ItemID, Period, Inventory1, Inventory2 
FROM tblInventory
```

[image: tblInventory]

I want to convert this table into this:

[image: tblconversion]

The period will be converted as Column such as Inventory1 -1 and Inventory2 -1 until 4th period, per period there are two columns included: inventory1 and inventory2.

I would like to ask help on how to code this in SQL. Thank you!

Comment: Use conditional aggregation or a `PIVOT`. This is, honestly, one of the most asked SQL [Server] questions on [so]; there are a wealth of [existing answers](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=make+rows+into+columns+in+sql+SQL+Server+site%3Astackoverflow.com) out there if you look for them.

Comment: I really want to use pivot but I really don't get it how to make it happen

Comment: If PIVOT is a requirement you should update the question so other solutions are not suggested.

Answer (score 0):

To use [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) with your example you want to [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15#unpivot-example) the data first.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            UP.PolicyId
            , UP.ItemId
            , CONCAT(UP.Inventories, '-', UP.Period) AS Inventories
            , UP.Inventory
        FROM
            tblInventory AS TI
        UNPIVOT
            (
                Inventory FOR Inventories IN (Inventory1, Inventory2)
            ) AS UP
    ) AS UNP
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(Inventory)
        FOR Inventories IN 
            (
                [Inventory1-1], [Inventory1-2], [Inventory1-3], [Inventory1-4]
                , [Inventory2-1], [Inventory2-2], [Inventory2-3], [Inventory2-4]
            )
    ) AS PVT
```